# C++ how to destroy an object in the base class with a derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

So in my program I have a derived class called hangman and a derived class called HangmanGraphics. The issue I'm having is after the game I want to reset my variables but for some reason my base constructor does not get restarted or even called. When I run the program it will go to the base constructor once but towards the end of the program when:

```
#include "player.h"
#include "hangman.h"
#include "HangmanGraphics.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    HangmanGraphics game2;
    while(1)
    {
        game2.Play();

        if(game2.Play()=='Y')
        {
            game2=HangmanGraphics();

            //in this part of the code I want to reset my base
            //constructor values but how do I do that by using the 
            //derived construtor  

            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your derived ctor call the base ctor?

Comment: @AmiTavory When I run the program even though I didnt put anything in the body of the derived constructor, the base constructor will get called but after I pass continue, the base constructor never gets called

Answer (score 0):

Cheap hack. Moving the definition of game2 into the while loop will provide a new game2 every pass though the loop:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        HangmanGraphics game2; // game2 created here
        // do stuff
    } // game2 destroyed here
}
```

There is not enough information provided in your question to say whether this is a good thing to do or a bad. But...

```
game2=HangmanGraphics();
```

will do five things:

1. Call HangmanGraphics's constructor to create a temporary HangmanGraphics.
2. This results in a call to Hangman's constructor
3. Call HangmanGraphics's = operator. If one has not been specified, the default will be to copy the contents of the right hand HangmanGraphics into the left. It will copy a pointer, but not the pointed-to data.
4. Call the destructor on the temporary HangmanGraphics
5. Which results in a call to Hangman's destructor

If you have any dynamically allocated storage in HangmanGraphics or Hangman, you need to read up on the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Anything dynamically allocated within the temporary HangmanGraphics and it's base Hangman will be (or should have been) deleted by the destructor. If a operator= was not custom-defined to handle the dynamic data, game2 now contains pointers to invalid storage.

Example:

```
class base
{
public:
    base(): baseval(number++), interestingData(new int(number++))
    {
        cout << "base ctor " << baseval << "," << * interestingData <<endl;
    }
    virtual ~base()
    {
        cout << "base dtor " << baseval << "," << * interestingData <<endl;
        delete interestingData;
    }
private:
    int baseval;
    int * interestingData;
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
    derived():base()
    {
        cout << "derived ctor" <<endl;
    }
    virtual ~derived()
    {
        cout << "derived dtor" <<endl;
    }
    derived & operator=(const derived & rhs) //only exists to do the cout
    {
        cout << "derived =" <<endl;
        base::operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived test;
    cout << "created test" << endl;
    test = derived();
    cout << "exit" << endl;
}
```

Output

```
base ctor 0,1
derived ctor
created test
base ctor 2,3
derived ctor
derived =
derived dtor
base dtor 2,3
exit
derived dtor
base dtor 2,4067440
```

interestingdata in the last print is smashed because the address it points to has been reassigned. Even more fun, it is about to be deleted a second time and that should crash your program.